# Настройка ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, xml

Есть некий `ConstaintLayout` в котором пытаюсь определить два элемента так, 
чтобы:

1. Они распологались по центру этого Layout'a
2. Картинка распологалась относительно справа кастомной `view`
3. И пожалуй самое главное, чтобы сама разметка `ConstraintLayout` была фиксированной величины.

Поехал по пунктам:

1. Для того чтобы они распологались по центру, использовал `app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"` для одного и второго элемента.
2. Кастомный текст выровнял относительно `parent` а само изображение относительно первой `view`.
3. Ну тут вообще беда, пробовал указывать в процентном соотношении аля использование `app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.44"` - не сработало, устанавливать фиксированный размер `app:layout_constraintWidth_max="200dp"` - не сработало. Возможно будут ещё какие то альтернативы или же что то явно я делаю не так?

Код(касательно 3-го пункта просто закинул два атрибута, их использовал раздельно)

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/categoryNameWithIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_max="75dp"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.44">

        <com.mandarine.features.common.widget.CustomTextView
            android:id="@+id/categoryNameView"
            style="@style/active_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/red"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/expandArrow"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_20"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_20"
            android:background="@color/green"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/dimen_8"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_right"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/categoryNameView" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: зачем вам фиксированной величины, вы хотите под каждый тип экрана делать отдельную разметку?  - это плохое решение Наверняка есть какие то критерии для относительного размера (какая то часть от экрана, размер равный другому элементу и т.п). Фиксированный размер на разных устройствах будет выглядеть абсолютно по разному и разметка "поплывет". Нарисуйте эскиз, что вы хотите получить в итоге и добавьте в вопрос

Comment: @pavlofff ну а разве в процентном соотношении это не есть "какая то часть от экрана".  Я знаю что по бокам у меня по 30% заняты другими элементами. Рисовать эскиз я к сожалению не буду/не умею, но если для примера то получается что идея данного ConstraintLayout'a это прямоугльник в 40% который находится в круге.
P.S. если я правильно понял, то возможно проставить ширину wrap_content после чего поставить ограничения по процентам, но данный атрибут который я указал в вопросе не срабатывает как надо.

Comment: а что за пределами этих 40%? дело в том, что ConstraintLayout - линейный контейнер (вложенность в другие контейнеры в нем не предусмотрена), то есть он позиционирует элементы на всем экране, а не какой то отдельный прямоугольник на часть экрана. Приложите тогда всю разметку экрана и скриншот, что получается и что вы бы хотели получить. По текстовому описанию трудно понять, что именно вам нужно в итоге.